# PHP counter still loses hits after file locking?

Tags: php, counter

I was using the following basic PHP:

```
<?php

    if (file_exists('count_file.txt')) 
    {
        $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', r);
        $dat = fread($fil, filesize('count_file.txt')); 
        echo $dat+1;
        fclose($fil);
        $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
        fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
    }

    else
    {
        $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
        fwrite($fil, 1);
        echo '1';
        fclose($fil);
    }
?>
```

as a hit counter (I'd rather not have one but it's been insisted we do).
The txt file keeps count of the hits and it works...however the counter randomly (sometimes after a few weeks, sometimes months later) decides to trip up and drops from say 4300 to 11.

I was told the fix for this was to use file locking so I changed to the following code:

```
<?php 

        $dat = file_get_contents('count_file.txt'); 
        $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', 'w'); 
        if (flock($fil, LOCK_EX)) { 
            echo $dat+1; 
            fwrite($fil, $dat+1); 
            flock($fil, LOCK_UN); 
        } 
        fclose($fil); 

    ?>
```

and now after a few days it has once again dropped from over 5000 to 13. Anyone have some idea as to why??

Comment: Why not to store counts in database? And if needed in external file, then run some script to get the number of hits?

Comment: I'm not PHP savvy so would not know how to go about storing it in a database?

Answer (score 1):

You fopen() the file for writing which truncates the file. If you cannot get a lock you close the file which may be truncated then to zero bytes.

Comment: if he doesnt get the lock that should usually mean that it is locked otherwise. how is he able to truncate it to zero then?

Comment: I think this can at least happen when process A (holding the lock) has written to the file and process B opens the file for writing before the file is unlocked and closed by A.

Answer (score 0):

Use fopen "a" instead of fopen "w" and then truncate the file:

```
<?php
    $dat = file_get_contents('count_file.txt'); 
    $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', 'a'); 
    if (flock($fil, LOCK_EX)) { 
        ftruncate($fil,0);
        echo $dat+1; 
        fwrite($fil, $dat+1); 
        flock($fil, LOCK_UN); 
    } 
    fclose($fil); 
?>
```